# Como dar color a un dato en DataTable usando un condicional

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

me ocupa lo siguiente
Tengo una tabla que obtiene resultado de un query en php y los envio en un arreglo json

```
    while($data = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
     {
       if ($data['status']==='0') {
         //$data['status'] = '<span class="badge badge-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ESPERANDO</span>';
         $data['status'] = 'ESPERANDO';
       } else {
         //$data['status'] = '<span class="badge badge-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> APROBADO</span>';
         $data['status'] = 'APROBADO';
       }

if ($data['monto'] < 0 ) {
$data['monto'] = number_format($data['monto'],2,',','.').' Bs';
//$data['monto'] = '<font color="red">'.number_format($data['monto'],2,',','.').' Bs</font>';
}
else {
$data['monto'] = number_format($data['monto'],2,',','.').' Bs';
//$data['monto'] = '<font color="green">'.number_format($data['monto'],2,',','.').' Bs</font>';
}



   $arreglo ["data"][] = $data;
 }

 echo json_encode($arreglo);
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($db);

}
```

Logicamente requiero dar un formato en la salida de datatable

```
    {"data":"monto"},

    {"data": "descripcion"},
```

{"data": "status" }
],

en el primer codigo me daba resultados de forma visual pero al implementar la opcion `"fixedHeader": true,` me da un error con los datos que son tratados antes del arreglo json.
el error que me daba es que me permitia seleccionar ejemplo:

`10 Bs"> 10 Bs` en el campo monto

`ESPERANDP"> ESPERANDO` en el campo status

Por ello me gustaria saber como darle formato condicional una vez recibido por el script de DataTable

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el error y dónde es el error?

Comment: Ejemplo si mi salida es `$data['status'] = '<span class="badge badge-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ESPERANDO</span>';` se ve bien en datatable pero al implementar `"fixedHeader": true,` me muestra la seleccion `ESPERANDO"> ESPERANDO`